# How to prepare a new MicroSDXC card for use with Android?

Tags: filesystems, android, sd-card

After buying a 64 GB MicroSDXC card and plugging it into my Android phone, it wasn't recognized. What do I need to do to use the space on this device? Many articles suggest installing closed source Windows programs for this, but I suspect it should be easy on Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the job:

1. Put the card in a card reader on your machine.
2. See the end of `dmesg` to find the device path (for example `/dev/sdx`).
3. If the device has any data on it, now is the time to back it up!
4. If the device was auto-mounted, `sudo umount /dev/sdx`.
5. Run `sudo gparted /dev/sdx` (or `gksudo`/`kdesu` if you have one of those).
6. If you have any partitions, delete them.
7. Create a new, unformatted partition taking up the full disk (this is the default), and with the label "msdos". I don't know whether the label is necessary, but some online guides mentioned it.
8. In a shell, run `sudo mkfs.exfat /dev/sdx1`.

Your SD card should now be ready to use in your Android phone.